# R Shiny Dashboard Slider Colors

Tags: css, r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyjs

I am building a R Shiny Dashboard and want to vary the background of the slider bar between the values of 0-50, 50-80, 80-100. The background when the slider bar goes from 0-50 should be red, 50-80 should be yellow and 80-100 should be green. I have

```
tags$style(HTML(".irs-bar-edge {background: red; width :50%}")),
```

but this makes it always red for the first 50%. How do I make it extend to the yellow and green stacks?

Comment: I wonder if applying a few gradient classes would help in your case. Perhaps this website could help? http://gradcolor.com/css3-gradient.php?c=3